# First-class variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, unification, first-class

I am implementing a [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm in JavaScript to compute the most general unifier of two given terms. In brief, unification is the process of taking two terms `t1` and `t2` and combining them into a new term `t` which is specialization of both `t1` and `t2`. Consider (note that variables are capitalized):

```
t1 := foo(jane, A, B)
t2 := foo(X, Y, rocks)
```

The specialization operator `⊏` denotes that “a is a specialization of b” in `a ⊏ b`. For example:

```
foo(jane, doe, X)   ⊏ t1
foo(on, the, rocks) ⊏ t2
```

A unifier of two terms is a term that specializes both those terms. For example:

```
foo(jane, street, rocks) ⊏ t1
foo(jane, street, rocks) ⊏ t2
```

The most general unifier of two terms is a unifier of those two terms which generalizes all other unifiers of those two terms (i.e. all the other unifiers specialize the most general unifier). For example:

```
foo(jane, street, rocks) ⊏ foo(jane, M, rocks)
```

Hence `foo(jane, M, rocks)` is the most general unifier of `t1` and `t2`. The following algorithm can be used to compute the most general unifier for terms of the first-order predicate logic.

1. If both `t1` and `t2` are constants then they unify if and only if they are the same constant (e.g. `jane`, `street` and `rocks` are constants).
2. If `t1` is a variable and `t2` is a non-variable (i.e. a constant or a complex term) then `t1` is instantiated to `t2` if and only if `t1` doesn't occur in `t2`.
3. If `t2` is a variable and `t1` is a non-variable (i.e. a constant or a complex term) then `t2` is instantiated to `t1` if and only if `t2` doesn't occur in `t1`.
4. If `t1` and `t2` are both variables then they are both instantiated to each other and are said to share values.
5. If both `t1` and `t2` are complex terms then they unify if and only if they are the same kind of complex term and their corresponding arguments unify.
6. Two terms unify if and only if they unify following the above five rules.

Anyway, this is how I wanted to tackle this problem:

```js
function variable(name) {
    return {
        type: "variable",
        name: name,
        term: null
    };
}

function constant(name) {
    return {
        type: "non_variable",
        name: name,
        args: []
    };
}

function complex(name, args) {
    return {
        type: "non_variable",
        name: name,
        args: args
    };
}
```

Now, we can define `t1` and `t2` as follows:

```js
var t1 = complex("foo", [constant("jane"), variable("A"), variable("B")]);
var t2 = complex("foo", [variable("X"), variable("Y"), constant("rocks")]);
```

Then we implement the unification algorithm:

```js
function unify(a, b) {
    var x = resolve(a);
    var y = resolve(b);

    var operation = 0;

    if (x.type === "non_variable") operation += 2;
    if (y.type === "non_variable") operation += 1;

    switch (operation) {
    case 0:
        return x.term = y.term = variable(x.name);
    case 1:
        if (occurs(x, y)) throw new Error(x.name + " occurs in " + show(y));
        return x.term = y;
    case 2:
        if (occurs(y, x)) throw new Error(y.name + " occurs in " + show(x));
        return y.term = x;
    case 3:
        if (x.name !== y.name) throw new
            Error(x.name + " and " + y.name + " are different terms");

        var ax = x.args;
        var ay = y.args;

        if (ax.length !== ay.length) throw new
            Error(x.name + " and " + y.name + " have different arities");

        var args = ax.map(function (t, i) {
            return unify(t, ay[i]);
        });

        return complex(x.name, args);
    }
}

function resolve(t) {
    if (t.type === "non_variable") return t;

    var v = t;
    while (v.type === "variable" && v.term) v = v.term;
    return t.term = v;
}

function show(t) {
    return t.name + "(" + t.args.map(function (t) {
        return t.type === "non_variable" &&
           t.args.length > 0 ? show(t) : t.name;
    }).join(", ") + ")";
}

function occurs(v, t) {
    return t.args.some(function (t) {
        t = resolve(t);
        return t.type === "variable" ? t === v : occurs(v, t);
    });
}
```

And it works:

```js
var t = unify(t1, t2);

alert(show(t));
```

```html
<script>
function variable(name) {
    return {
        type: "variable",
        name: name,
        term: null
    };
}

function constant(name) {
    return {
        type: "non_variable",
        name: name,
        args: []
    };
}

function complex(name, args) {
    return {
        type: "non_variable",
        name: name,
        args: args
    };
}

var t1 = complex("foo", [constant("jane"), variable("A"), variable("B")]);
var t2 = complex("foo", [variable("X"), variable("Y"), constant("rocks")]);

function unify(a, b) {
    var x = resolve(a);
    var y = resolve(b);

    var operation = 0;

    if (x.type === "non_variable") operation += 2;
    if (y.type === "non_variable") operation += 1;

    switch (operation) {
    case 0:
        return x.term = y.term = variable(x.name);
    case 1:
        if (occurs(x, y)) throw new Error(x.name + " occurs in " + show(y));
        return x.term = y;
    case 2:
        if (occurs(y, x)) throw new Error(y.name + " occurs in " + show(x));
        return y.term = x;
    case 3:
        if (x.name !== y.name) throw new
            Error(x.name + " and " + y.name + " are different terms");

        var ax = x.args;
        var ay = y.args;

        if (ax.length !== ay.length) throw new
            Error(x.name + " and " + y.name + " have different arities");

        var args = ax.map(function (t, i) {
            return unify(t, ay[i]);
        });

        return complex(x.name, args);
    }
}

function resolve(t) {
    if (t.type === "non_variable") return t;

    var v = t;
    while (v.type === "variable" && v.term) v = v.term;
    return t.term = v;
}

function show(t) {
    return t.name + "(" + t.args.map(function (t) {
        return t.type === "non_variable" &&
           t.args.length > 0 ? show(t) : t.name;
    }).join(", ") + ")";
}

function occurs(v, t) {
    return t.args.some(function (t) {
        t = resolve(t);
        return t.type === "variable" ? t === v : occurs(v, t);
    });
}
</script>
```

However, I have only one problem: the way I have implemented first-class variables is not very nice. The way I have implemented it is as follows:

1. Every variable has a `term` property which is `null` initially (to show that the variable has not yet been instantiated).
2. When a variable is unified with a non-variable its `term` property is set to the non-variable, which is fine.
3. However, when a variable is unified with another variable then a problem arises. We can't set the `term` property of one variable to the other because that would result in a cyclic reference. Therefore, I create a new variable and set both `term` properties of both the variables to the new variable.
4. This causes another problem. If we unify lots of variables then the `term` chain will become longer which is why I need the `resolve` function in my code above. It traverses the `term` chain and returns the last term in the chain.

So my question is whether there is a better way to create first-class variables in JavaScript (i.e. one in which sharing values between two variables doesn't require the use of a `term` chain). If there is a better way then please describe the algorithm.

Comment: Do you have an updated implementation that you'd care to share?

Comment: It'd be incredible helpful if there were a sound unification algorithm implemented in JS out there. Maybe you could share your implementation. It does not really matter if it is partial or complete. Either way it would help the JS/TS community to further evolve towards FP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you could use a disjoint-set-forest that the terms would be members of. This has efficient union/find.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests

A bit of googling reaffirms that this is used in prolog unification implementations.

http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2318&context=cstech

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an example code to show how to use it?

Comment: Hey, what do you know? I already have the path compression optimization implemented in my `resolve` function. =)